# Filtrado incremental en JQuery

Tags: json

Tengo el siguiente codigo en JQuery, una funcion para filtrar un array que almaceno en una variable global,se trata de un JSON que pido por AJAX.

```js
function filtrar(dato){
       var filtrado = content.filter(function (a) {
                return a.nombre == dato;
            });
       if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
      
        $("#resultado").empty(); 
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado");                 
       }

} 
 
  
};
```

Funciona perfecto, pero filtra, osea borra toda la tabla y muestra los que coinciden estrictamente, osea todo el nombre de producto en este caso.
Como puedo filtrar caracter por caracter si el nombre contiene parte de la cadena buscada?

```js
var content;
$(document).ready(function() {
listar();
var nombreBusqueda;

 $("#nombre").keyup(function() {
            
        nombreBusqueda=$("#nombre").val();
        filtrar(nombreBusqueda);
    }
);
});
```

Ahi arriba el codigo cuando cargo la pagina y tecleo una busqueda.
Quiero buscar en el array y no en el DOM porque pienso paginar a futuro y quiero buscar sobre el total de registros

Answer (score 0):

Para compara cadenas y asegurarte de que un texto esta incluido dentro otro puedes utilizar el metodo `indexOf` este devuelve la posición desde se encuentra la palabra, sino returna -1

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Blue")    // returns 0
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Blute")   // returns -1
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Whale",0) // returns 5
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Whale",5) // returns 5
"Blue Whale".indexOf("",9)      // returns 9
"Blue Whale".indexOf("",10)     // returns 10
"Blue Whale".indexOf("",11)     // returns 10
```

El método indexOf es sensible a mayúsculas. Por ejemplo, la siguiente expresión devuelve -1:

```
"Ballena Azul".indexOf("azul")
```

Para resolverte eso puedes pasar todo a minuscula o mayuscula durante la busqueda,

```
$textoCompleto = "Ballena Azul"; 
$textoABuscar = "aZUl";
$textoCompleto.toLowerCase().indexOf($textoABuscar.toLowerCase()); //returns 8
```

Comment: Claro, entonces tendria que recorrer el array inicial y poner un condicional si es distinto de -1. Pero tendria que recorrer solo la columna nombre, ya que el JSON tiene el id  y el precio entre otros.

Answer (score 0):

simplemente itere sobre el nombre dentro del array utilizando IndexOf como la planteo Samir Llorente.

```js
function filtrar(dato){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(dato.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);
          console.log("se encuentra objeto!.");
       
    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
      $("#resultado").empty();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado");                 
       }
 
 
  
}};
```